# Showing that no solutions of an ODE with periodic coefficients remains bounded.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We consider $x'' + (a+b\cos(t))x = 0$ (no conditions are given on $a,b$). Suppose we have solutions $u,v$ such that $u(0)=1, u'(0)=0, v(0)=0$, and $v'(0)=1$. Set $F(a,b)=u(2\pi)+v'(2\pi)$, and suppose $|F(a,b)|>2$. Conclude that no solutions remain bounded for all $t$.

Usually when I see second order equations, I write it as a first order system:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix} ' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -(a+b\cos(t)) & 0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Call the $2\times 2$ matrix above $A(t)$. Then $A(t)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic matrix. From here, I'm not sure what to do. I know that there exists nonvanishing $2\pi$-periodic functions $p_1,p_2$ such that $e^{\lambda t}p_1(t)$ and $e^{-\lambda t}p_2(t)$ solve the system (here $\lambda$ is such that $e^{2\pi \lambda}$ is a characteristic multiplier). But I'm not sure if this is even useful nor am I sure how to apply the assumption on $F$.

Thank you.

Comment: the matrix does not does not describe your diff eq.  How about you move the x'' to the opposite side of the equal sign and integrate both sides twice.

Comment: your ODE currently reads $x" + (a+b\cos(t)) = 0.$ the rest of it suggests you meant $x'' + (a+b\cos(t))x = 0.$ Also when you use a double quote, Latex does not interpret that as derivatives

Comment: @WillJagy Thanks, I wrote it in a rush, just edited.

Comment: Still no $x$ term in the ODE, just $x''$

Comment: Fixed. Edited too fast again. Now everything should be correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, at least I can show you what the question is intended to be. This is from my college textbook, Brauer and Nohel (1969). This is about Floquet's Theorem. You are asked about part (d) of exercise 6.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, seeing parts (a) and (c) in particular should be helpful.

Comment: Pretty sure I got part (d) now, so I know there exists at least one unbounded solution, but how can this show me that all solutions are unbounded?

Comment: @Curious I'm not so sure that all possible solutions must be unbounded. Probably most, but if you take just the solution with real part of the characteristic negative it stays bounded

Comment: Alright then, perhaps the person who came up with the question made a mistake. I'm satisfied with just the existence of unbounded solutions then.